# GDB print the fields of a structure

Tags: c++, c, gdb

I've a

```
struct addrinfo *s;
```

and i want to see the fields

```
struct sockaddr *ai_addr;
```

inside my struct (s) when I'm in debug mode. I use code-blocks ide for testing my programs, and in the Debug Watches window I have set the correct watch

```
*s->ai_addr
```

but it print only the memory address. Then I use the debugger console of the ide, and i try to print the ai_addr struct with this command

```
p s->ai_addr
```

but gdb print the address again.
How I can print correctly the content of the ai_addr struct in debug mode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you trying to print `ai_addr` which is pointer aka address